# TCL glob to use character count

Tags: tcl, glob

I am wondering if TCL glob has capabilities to support count for a character set. Let's say I have a regular expression that catches a certain representation  of a number with 3 decimal places.

```
regexp {_([01]p[0-9]{3})_} $str dmy val
```

Example stuff I'm looking for

```
blabla_0p123_bla
```

In regexp the {3} is easy. I wanted to try this in glob to find files with that pattern.

```
glob *_[01]p[0-9]{3}_*
```

It failed.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Tcl's globbing matcher (usually described as the `string match` matcher, since the `glob` command itself has extra capabilities) is too simple minded for that; it doesn't support it and won't ever do. The reason for the second part is that what you're asking for would interfere with the extended mode in `glob`, which supports the syntax `{alt1,alt2,alt3}` as a way of describing *alternatives* that can be matched, meaning that there's no spare syntax for counting things. (At some point, that might get ported back into `string match`… but it isn't a very high priority task to be honest.)

Comment: lsearch has a '-regexp' option. Having the same in glob would not interfere with alternatives as it would bifurcate into an entire new processing environment. Alas, I am not going to argue what TCL developers would put into the language. It's not going to happen anyways.